# Various errors/warnings during conversion from TS to PNG though the results seem to be unaffected

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I want to extract the individual frames from a `.TS` video file using the following command:

```
ffmpeg -i test.ts frame_%03d.png
```

Though the results look valid, i.e. the PNG files look like the frames of the video, I get the following errors/warnings (they are highlighted in red font color):

```
...
[mpeg2video @ 0x1742840] Invalid frame dimensions 0x0.
...
[mpeg2video @ 0x1743b80] ac-tex damaged at 5 1303.88 bitrate=N/A dup=7 drop=0    
[mpeg2video @ 0x1743b80] Warning MVs not available
...
```

I don't have any experience using `ffmpeg` so I can't tell whether these information are relevant or can be safely ignored. In the end I would like to understand the reason for these warnings and if the results may be flawed. I don't have any control over nor details on how the original `.TS` video files are created (they are given to me from an external source).

I did some research on each individual warning but couldn't find much information. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20061180/3767239) states that `Invalid frame dimensions 0x0` possibly means that the wrong data is passed to the decoder, so does that mean the `TS` file is corrupted?

### Full output of ffmpeg command

```
ffmpeg version 2.8.15-0ubuntu0.16.04.1 Copyright (c) 2000-2018 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 5.4.0 (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.10) 20160609
  configuration: --prefix=/usr --extra-version=0ubuntu0.16.04.1 --build-suffix=-ffmpeg --toolchain=hardened --libdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --incdir=/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu --cc=cc --cxx=g++ --enable-gpl --enable-shared --disable-stripping --disable-decoder=libopenjpeg --disable-decoder=libschroedinger --enable-avresample --enable-avisynth --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libcdio --enable-libflite --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libmodplug --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librtmp --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx265 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzvbi --enable-openal --enable-opengl --enable-x11grab --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libiec61883 --enable-libzmq --enable-frei0r --enable-libx264 --enable-libopencv
  libavutil      54. 31.100 / 54. 31.100
  libavcodec     56. 60.100 / 56. 60.100
  libavformat    56. 40.101 / 56. 40.101
  libavdevice    56.  4.100 / 56.  4.100
  libavfilter     5. 40.101 /  5. 40.101
  libavresample   2.  1.  0 /  2.  1.  0
  libswscale      3.  1.101 /  3.  1.101
  libswresample   1.  2.101 /  1.  2.101
  libpostproc    53.  3.100 / 53.  3.100
[mpeg2video @ 0x1742840] Invalid frame dimensions 0x0.
    Last message repeated 3 times
Input #0, mpegts, from 'test.ts':
  Duration: 00:00:04.68, start: 11255.212589, bitrate: 5458 kb/s
  Program 1 
    Stream #0:0[0x3e9]: Video: mpeg2video (Main) ([2][0][0][0] / 0x0002), yuv420p(tv), 720x576 [SAR 16:15 DAR 4:3], max. 9999 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 90k tbn, 50 tbc
    Stream #0:1[0x3ea]: Audio: mp2 ([4][0][0][0] / 0x0004), 48000 Hz, stereo, s16p, 128 kb/s
Output #0, image2, to 'frame_%03d.png':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf56.40.101
    Stream #0:0: Video: png, rgb24, 720x576 [SAR 16:15 DAR 4:3], q=2-31, 200 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbn, 25 tbc
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc56.60.100 png
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (mpeg2video (native) -> png (native))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[mpeg2video @ 0x1743b80] ac-tex damaged at 5 1303.88 bitrate=N/A dup=7 drop=0    
[mpeg2video @ 0x1743b80] Warning MVs not available
[mpeg2video @ 0x1743b80] concealing 1035 DC, 1035 AC, 1035 MV errors in B frame
frame=  113 fps= 63 q=-0.0 Lsize=N/A time=00:00:04.52 bitrate=N/A dup=8 drop=0    
video:12865kB audio:0kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: unknown
```

### Screenshot of output (including font colors)

[image: Screenshot]

### Log data from `-report`

```
ffmpeg started on 2019-12-10 at 15:30:22
Report written to "ffmpeg-20191210-153022.log"
Command line:
ffmpeg -i test.ts "frame_%03d.png" -report
ffmpeg version 2.8.15-0ubuntu0.16.04.1 Copyright (c) 2000-2018 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 5.4.0 (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.10) 20160609
  configuration: --prefix=/usr --extra-version=0ubuntu0.16.04.1 --build-suffix=-ffmpeg --toolchain=hardened --libdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --incdir=/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu --cc=cc --cxx=g++ --enable-gpl --enable-shared --disable-stripping --disable-decoder=libopenjpeg --disable-decoder=libschroedinger --enable-avresample --enable-avisynth --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libcdio --enable-libflite --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libmodplug --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librtmp --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx265 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzvbi --enable-openal --enable-opengl --enable-x11grab --e  libavutil      54. 31.100 / 54. 31.100
  libavcodec     56. 60.100 / 56. 60.100
  libavformat    56. 40.101 / 56. 40.101
  libavdevice    56.  4.100 / 56.  4.100
  libavfilter     5. 40.101 /  5. 40.101
  libavresample   2.  1.  0 /  2.  1.  0
  libswscale      3.  1.101 /  3.  1.101
  libswresample   1.  2.101 /  1.  2.101
  libpostproc    53.  3.100 / 53.  3.100
Splitting the commandline.
Reading option '-i' ... matched as input url with argument 'test.ts'.
Reading option 'frame_%03d.png' ... matched as output url.
Reading option '-report' ... matched as option 'report' (generate a report) with argument '1'.
Finished splitting the commandline.
Parsing a group of options: global .
Applying option report (generate a report) with argument 1.
Successfully parsed a group of options.
Parsing a group of options: input url test.ts.
Successfully parsed a group of options.
Opening an input file: test.ts.
[mpegts @ 0xe54c40] Format mpegts probed with size=2048 and score=100
[mpegts @ 0xe54c40] stream=0 stream_type=2 pid=3e9 prog_reg_desc=
[mpegts @ 0xe54c40] stream=1 stream_type=4 pid=3ea prog_reg_desc=
[mpegts @ 0xe54c40] Before avformat_find_stream_info() pos: 0 bytes read:32768 seeks:0
[mpeg2video @ 0xe59080] Invalid frame dimensions 0x0.
[mpeg2video @ 0xe59080] Invalid frame dimensions 0x0.
[mpeg2video @ 0xe59080] Invalid frame dimensions 0x0.
[mpeg2video @ 0xe59080] Invalid frame dimensions 0x0.
[mpegts @ 0xe54c40] rfps: 24.916667 0.011489
[mpegts @ 0xe54c40] rfps: 24.916667 0.011489
[mpegts @ 0xe54c40] rfps: 25.000000 0.000024
[mpegts @ 0xe54c40] rfps: 25.000000 0.000024
[mpegts @ 0xe54c40] rfps: 25.083333 0.010963
[mpegts @ 0xe54c40] rfps: 50.000000 0.000096
[mpegts @ 0xe54c40] rfps: 50.000000 0.000096
[mpegts @ 0xe54c40] After avformat_find_stream_info() pos: 0 bytes read:3446000 seeks:2 frames:294
Input #0, mpegts, from 'test.ts':
  Duration: 00:00:04.68, start: 11255.212589, bitrate: 5458 kb/s
  Program 1 
    Stream #0:0[0x3e9], 111, 1/90000: Video: mpeg2video (Main) ([2][0][0][0] / 0x0002), yuv420p(tv), 720x576 [SAR 16:15 DAR 4:3], max. 9999 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 90k tbn, 50 tbc
    Stream #0:1[0x3ea], 183, 1/90000: Audio: mp2 ([4][0][0][0] / 0x0004), 48000 Hz, stereo, s16p, 128 kb/s
Successfully opened the file.
Parsing a group of options: output url frame_%03d.png.
Successfully parsed a group of options.
Opening an output file: frame_%03d.png.
Successfully opened the file.
detected 4 logical cores
[graph 0 input from stream 0:0 @ 0xe839e0] Setting 'video_size' to value '720x576'
[graph 0 input from stream 0:0 @ 0xe839e0] Setting 'pix_fmt' to value '0'
[graph 0 input from stream 0:0 @ 0xe839e0] Setting 'time_base' to value '1/90000'
[graph 0 input from stream 0:0 @ 0xe839e0] Setting 'pixel_aspect' to value '16/15'
[graph 0 input from stream 0:0 @ 0xe839e0] Setting 'sws_param' to value 'flags=2'
[graph 0 input from stream 0:0 @ 0xe839e0] Setting 'frame_rate' to value '25/1'
[graph 0 input from stream 0:0 @ 0xe839e0] w:720 h:576 pixfmt:yuv420p tb:1/90000 fr:25/1 sar:16/15 sws_param:flags=2
[format @ 0xe83b60] compat: called with args=[rgb24|rgba|rgb48be|rgba64be|pal8|gray|ya8|gray16be|ya16be|monob]
[format @ 0xe83b60] Setting 'pix_fmts' to value 'rgb24|rgba|rgb48be|rgba64be|pal8|gray|ya8|gray16be|ya16be|monob'
[auto-inserted scaler 0 @ 0xe84aa0] Setting 'flags' to value 'bicubic'
[auto-inserted scaler 0 @ 0xe84aa0] w:iw h:ih flags:'bicubic' interl:0
[format @ 0xe83b60] auto-inserting filter 'auto-inserted scaler 0' between the filter 'Parsed_null_0' and the filter 'format'
[AVFilterGraph @ 0xe828c0] query_formats: 4 queried, 2 merged, 1 already done, 0 delayed
[auto-inserted scaler 0 @ 0xe84aa0] picking rgb24 out of 9 ref:yuv420p alpha:0
[auto-inserted scaler 0 @ 0xe84aa0] w:720 h:576 fmt:yuv420p sar:16/15 -> w:720 h:576 fmt:rgb24 sar:16/15 flags:0x4
Output #0, image2, to 'frame_%03d.png':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf56.40.101
    Stream #0:0, 0, 1/25: Video: png, rgb24, 720x576 [SAR 16:15 DAR 4:3], q=2-31, 200 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbn, 25 tbc
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc56.60.100 png
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (mpeg2video (native) -> png (native))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[mpegts @ 0xe54c40] Correcting start time by 164922
*** 7 dup!
[AVIOContext @ 0x1049500] Statistics: 0 seeks, 3 writeouts
[AVIOContext @ 0x1049200] Statistics: 0 seeks, 3 writeouts
[AVIOContext @ 0x1049440] Statistics: 0 seeks, 3 writeouts
[AVIOContext @ 0x1049200] Statistics: 0 seeks, 3 writeouts
[AVIOContext @ 0x104a5c0] Statistics: 0 seeks, 3 writeouts
[AVIOContext @ 0x104a620] Statistics: 0 seeks, 3 writeouts
Cliping frame in rate conversion by 0.003609
[AVIOContext @ 0x104ad80] Statistics: 0 seeks, 3 writeouts
[AVIOContext @ 0x104a960] Statistics: 0 seeks, 3 writeouts
Cliping frame in rate conversion by 0.001381
[AVIOContext @ 0x1057f20] Statistics: 0 seeks, 4 writeouts
[AVIOContext @ 0x1057f20] Statistics: 0 seeks, 4 writeouts
Cliping frame in rate conversion by 0.000267
[AVIOContext @ 0x10490c0] Statistics: 0 seeks, 4 writeouts
Cliping frame in rate conversion by 0.003319
[AVIOContext @ 0x104aec0] Statistics: 0 seeks, 5 writeouts
Cliping frame in rate conversion by 0.001106
[AVIOContext @ 0x1048fa0] Statistics: 0 seeks, 5 writeouts
[AVIOContext @ 0x104cee0] Statistics: 0 seeks, 4 writeouts
Cliping frame in rate conversion by 0.000267
[AVIOContext @ 0x104a340] Statistics: 0 seeks, 5 writeouts
[AVIOContext @ 0x1058440] Statistics: 0 seeks, 5 writeouts
[AVIOContext @ 0x104b920] Statistics: 0 seeks, 5 writeouts
Cliping frame in rate conversion by 0.001381
[AVIOContext @ 0x1049180] Statistics: 0 seeks, 4 writeouts
Cliping frame in rate conversion by 0.001930
[AVIOContext @ 0x10582a0] Statistics: 0 seeks, 4 writeouts
Cliping frame in rate conversion by 0.000542
[AVIOContext @ 0x1049900] Statistics: 0 seeks, 3 writeouts
[AVIOContext @ 0x104a2e0] Statistics: 0 seeks, 4 writeouts
[AVIOContext @ 0x1049d60] Statistics: 0 seeks, 4 writeouts
Cliping frame in rate conversion by 0.004433
[AVIOContext @ 0x104aa80] Statistics: 0 seeks, 4 writeouts
Cliping frame in rate conversion by 0.001381
[AVIOContext @ 0x10499c0] Statistics: 0 seeks, 4 writeouts
[AVIOContext @ 0x1058080] Statistics: 0 seeks, 4 writeouts
frame=   29 fps=0.0 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:00:01.00 bitrate=N/A dup=7 drop=0    
Cliping frame in rate conversion by 0.003044
[AVIOContext @ 0x104ada0] Statistics: 0 seeks, 4 writeouts
Cliping frame in rate conversion by 0.003044
[AVIOContext @ 0x104a9a0] Statistics: 0 seeks, 5 writeouts
Cliping frame in rate conversion by 0.001106
[AVIOContext @ 0x104a600] Statistics: 0 seeks, 5 writeouts
Cliping frame in rate conversion by 0.004433
[AVIOContext @ 0x104b860] Statistics: 0 seeks, 5 writeouts
Cliping frame in rate conversion by 0.002769
[AVIOContext @ 0x104cd80] Statistics: 0 seeks, 4 writeouts
[AVIOContext @ 0x10496c0] Statistics: 0 seeks, 4 writeouts
Cliping frame in rate conversion by 0.003319
[AVIOContext @ 0x104d720] Statistics: 0 seeks, 3 writeouts
[AVIOContext @ 0x12c7940] Statistics: 0 seeks, 3 writeouts
Cliping frame in rate conversion by 0.002220
[AVIOContext @ 0x10578a0] Statistics: 0 seeks, 5 writeouts
Cliping frame in rate conversion by 0.002220
[AVIOContext @ 0x104dfe0] Statistics: 0 seeks, 5 writeouts
Cliping frame in rate conversion by 0.001930
[AVIOContext @ 0x10497c0] Statistics: 0 seeks, 5 writeouts
Cliping frame in rate conversion by 0.000267
[AVIOContext @ 0x10497a0] Statistics: 0 seeks, 5 writeouts
[AVIOContext @ 0x104b540] Statistics: 0 seeks, 4 writeouts
Cliping frame in rate conversion by 0.002220
[AVIOContext @ 0x104d480] Statistics: 0 seeks, 5 writeouts
[AVIOContext @ 0x1049bc0] Statistics: 0 seeks, 5 writeouts
Cliping frame in rate conversion by 0.001656
[AVIOContext @ 0x10497e0] Statistics: 0 seeks, 5 writeouts
Cliping frame in rate conversion by 0.000832
[AVIOContext @ 0x1049da0] Statistics: 0 seeks, 4 writeouts
Cliping frame in rate conversion by 0.001656
[AVIOContext @ 0x104d840] Statistics: 0 seeks, 4 writeouts
Cliping frame in rate conversion by 0.001930
[AVIOContext @ 0x10498a0] Statistics: 0 seeks, 3 writeouts
Cliping frame in rate conversion by 0.000832
[AVIOContext @ 0x10576c0] Statistics: 0 seeks, 4 writeouts
Cliping frame in rate conversion by 0.000832
[AVIOContext @ 0x104baa0] Statistics: 0 seeks, 4 writeouts
Cliping frame in rate conversion by 0.001381
[AVIOContext @ 0x1049660] Statistics: 0 seeks, 3 writeouts
[AVIOContext @ 0x10497a0] Statistics: 0 seeks, 4 writeouts
frame=   52 fps= 50 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:00:01.92 bitrate=N/A dup=7 drop=0    
[AVIOContext @ 0x10582c0] Statistics: 0 seeks, 4 writeouts
[AVIOContext @ 0x104d520] Statistics: 0 seeks, 4 writeouts
[AVIOContext @ 0x1049ee0] Statistics: 0 seeks, 5 writeouts
[AVIOContext @ 0x1058440] Statistics: 0 seeks, 5 writeouts
[AVIOContext @ 0x104d2a0] Statistics: 0 seeks, 5 writeouts
[AVIOContext @ 0x104dbc0] Statistics: 0 seeks, 4 writeouts
[AVIOContext @ 0x104b4c0] Statistics: 0 seeks, 4 writeouts
[AVIOContext @ 0x104b8a0] Statistics: 0 seeks, 3 writeouts
[AVIOContext @ 0x104df40] Statistics: 0 seeks, 4 writeouts
[AVIOContext @ 0x104b6a0] Statistics: 0 seeks, 4 writeouts
[AVIOContext @ 0x104b980] Statistics: 0 seeks, 4 writeouts
[AVIOContext @ 0x104ba60] Statistics: 0 seeks, 4 writeouts
[AVIOContext @ 0x104d4a0] Statistics: 0 seeks, 4 writeouts
[AVIOContext @ 0x104cee0] Statistics: 0 seeks, 4 writeouts
[AVIOContext @ 0x104b5c0] Statistics: 0 seeks, 5 writeouts
[AVIOContext @ 0x10556c0] Statistics: 0 seeks, 5 writeouts
[AVIOContext @ 0x104b7c0] Statistics: 0 seeks, 5 writeouts
[AVIOContext @ 0x12c89a0] Statistics: 0 seeks, 4 writeouts
[AVIOContext @ 0x104d240] Statistics: 0 seeks, 4 writeouts
[AVIOContext @ 0x104da60] Statistics: 0 seeks, 3 writeouts
[AVIOContext @ 0x104b120] Statistics: 0 seeks, 4 writeouts
[AVIOContext @ 0x104da60] Statistics: 0 seeks, 4 writeouts
[AVIOContext @ 0x104d040] Statistics: 0 seeks, 4 writeouts
frame=   75 fps= 49 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:00:02.84 bitrate=N/A dup=7 drop=0    
[AVIOContext @ 0x1055640] Statistics: 0 seeks, 4 writeouts
Cliping frame in rate conversion by 0.002220
[AVIOContext @ 0x104da40] Statistics: 0 seeks, 4 writeouts
Cliping frame in rate conversion by 0.001381
[AVIOContext @ 0x104a2e0] Statistics: 0 seeks, 4 writeouts
Cliping frame in rate conversion by 0.001930
[AVIOContext @ 0x1055d40] Statistics: 0 seeks, 5 writeouts
Cliping frame in rate conversion by 0.003044
[AVIOContext @ 0x104d140] Statistics: 0 seeks, 5 writeouts
Cliping frame in rate conversion by 0.002769
[AVIOContext @ 0x104dfe0] Statistics: 0 seeks, 5 writeouts
Cliping frame in rate conversion by 0.002769
[AVIOContext @ 0x1049dc0] Statistics: 0 seeks, 4 writeouts
Cliping frame in rate conversion by 0.001930
[AVIOContext @ 0x104dbe0] Statistics: 0 seeks, 4 writeouts
Cliping frame in rate conversion by 0.001106
[AVIOContext @ 0x104d320] Statistics: 0 seeks, 2 writeouts
[AVIOContext @ 0x1049e40] Statistics: 0 seeks, 3 writeouts
[AVIOContext @ 0x104a820] Statistics: 0 seeks, 4 writeouts
[AVIOContext @ 0x1049da0] Statistics: 0 seeks, 4 writeouts
[AVIOContext @ 0x104d400] Statistics: 0 seeks, 6 writeouts
[AVIOContext @ 0x104cfc0] Statistics: 0 seeks, 6 writeouts
[AVIOContext @ 0x1049400] Statistics: 0 seeks, 5 writeouts
[AVIOContext @ 0x1049f00] Statistics: 0 seeks, 5 writeouts
[AVIOContext @ 0x104d0e0] Statistics: 0 seeks, 5 writeouts
frame=   92 fps= 44 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:00:03.52 bitrate=N/A dup=7 drop=0    
[AVIOContext @ 0x104a500] Statistics: 0 seeks, 5 writeouts
[AVIOContext @ 0x10493e0] Statistics: 0 seeks, 4 writeouts
[AVIOContext @ 0x1049760] Statistics: 0 seeks, 4 writeouts
[AVIOContext @ 0x1057f20] Statistics: 0 seeks, 3 writeouts
[AVIOContext @ 0x1049540] Statistics: 0 seeks, 4 writeouts
[AVIOContext @ 0x1049380] Statistics: 0 seeks, 4 writeouts
[AVIOContext @ 0x1049a80] Statistics: 0 seeks, 4 writeouts
[AVIOContext @ 0x10498a0] Statistics: 0 seeks, 5 writeouts
[AVIOContext @ 0x104d240] Statistics: 0 seeks, 4 writeouts
Cliping frame in rate conversion by 0.013878
[AVIOContext @ 0x104c260] Statistics: 0 seeks, 4 writeouts
Cliping frame in rate conversion by 0.011940
[AVIOContext @ 0x104cf00] Statistics: 0 seeks, 5 writeouts
Cliping frame in rate conversion by 0.012215
[AVIOContext @ 0x104c4c0] Statistics: 0 seeks, 5 writeouts
Cliping frame in rate conversion by 0.013878
[AVIOContext @ 0x104dbc0] Statistics: 0 seeks, 5 writeouts
Cliping frame in rate conversion by 0.015266
[AVIOContext @ 0x104db40] Statistics: 0 seeks, 4 writeouts
Cliping frame in rate conversion by 0.012764
[AVIOContext @ 0x10492c0] Statistics: 0 seeks, 4 writeouts
Cliping frame in rate conversion by 0.013603
[AVIOContext @ 0x1048ee0] Statistics: 0 seeks, 3 writeouts
Cliping frame in rate conversion by 0.012764
[AVIOContext @ 0x10490c0] Statistics: 0 seeks, 4 writeouts
Cliping frame in rate conversion by 0.013054
[AVIOContext @ 0x104d060] Statistics: 0 seeks, 4 writeouts
[mpeg2video @ 0xe5a3c0] ac-tex damaged at 5 13
[mpeg2video @ 0xe5a3c0] Warning MVs not available
[mpeg2video @ 0xe5a3c0] concealing 1035 DC, 1035 AC, 1035 MV errors in B frame
Cliping frame in rate conversion by 0.012489
[AVIOContext @ 0x10584a0] Statistics: 0 seeks, 4 writeouts
*** 1 dup!
[AVIOContext @ 0x104c260] Statistics: 0 seeks, 4 writeouts
[AVIOContext @ 0x1049240] Statistics: 0 seeks, 4 writeouts
[output stream 0:0 @ 0xe54b40] EOF on sink link output stream 0:0:default.
No more output streams to write to, finishing.
[AVIOContext @ 0x104c240] Statistics: 0 seeks, 4 writeouts
[AVIOContext @ 0x104c240] Statistics: 0 seeks, 4 writeouts
[AVIOContext @ 0x104d100] Statistics: 0 seeks, 5 writeouts
[AVIOContext @ 0x104d100] Statistics: 0 seeks, 5 writeouts
frame=  113 fps= 43 q=-0.0 Lsize=N/A time=00:00:04.52 bitrate=N/A dup=8 drop=0    
video:12865kB audio:0kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: unknown
Input file #0 (test.ts):
  Input stream #0:0 (video): 111 packets read (2971434 bytes); 105 frames decoded; 
  Input stream #0:1 (audio): 0 packets read (0 bytes); 
  Total: 111 packets (2971434 bytes) demuxed
Output file #0 (frame_%03d.png):
  Output stream #0:0 (video): 113 frames encoded; 113 packets muxed (13173614 bytes); 
  Total: 113 packets (13173614 bytes) muxed
105 frames successfully decoded, 0 decoding errors
[AVIOContext @ 0xe5d680] Statistics: 6642000 bytes read, 2 seeks
```

Answer (score 1):

The messages mean that some of the frames in the input video stream are corrupted or malformed, usually the former. There's nothing to be done about it.

Based on `dup=8`, there may be up to 8 corrupt frames, although ffmpeg may dupe frames if the input is VFR and the output is CFR (like image sequences), so could be fewer.

Comment: Is there a way to know which frames are corrupted and in which way they are corrupted? Are these frames skipped by `ffmpeg`? Since I lack experience with `ffmpeg` or video streams in general it's difficult to imagine what "corrupted" means in this context and what the consequences for the resulting images are. The video file is generated by a [Hauppauge USB-Live2 (+ corresponding software)](https://www.hauppauge.com/pages/products/data_usblive2.html) in case that matters.

Comment: Run your command with -report added and upload report.

Comment: Thanks, I included the log in the question.